# Running first application on Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to run my first hello world application on the 2.3.1 emulator but I get the following error message: "The application Hello World (process com.helloworld) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

What could be the reason this is happening?

Here is the source code:

```
 package com.helloworld;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

     Button button;
     int touchCount;

     @Override 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         button = new Button(this); //create the Button
         button.setText( "Touch me" ); //set its initial text
         button.setOnClickListener(this); 
         setContentView(button);    
          }

     public void onClick(View v) {
         touchCount++; //Increase the touchCount
         button.setText("Touched me " + touchCount + "time(s)");
     }  
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.helloworld/com.helloworld.HelloWorld.activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.helloworld.HelloWorld.activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.helloworld-1.apk]
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.helloworld.HelloWorld.activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.helloworld-1.apk]
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
05-10 17:32:18.749: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     ... 11 more
```

http://pastebin.com/7R9pF34w

Comment: You should no post a screenshot of the error, but the StackTrace.

Comment: Please post all relevant source code, Logcat output, etc. within your question rather than using external sites. I can't even view the image because work IT policy blocks it.

Comment: StackTrace is not showing any error ! and I ran the code and its running fine , but mine is 2.2 API level 8

Comment: That's actually the console output. The stacktrace will be in Logcat. If on Eclipse, you can find it under `Window->Show View->Other...->Android->Logcat`

Comment: @kachilous this is not the stacktrace from the position where the exception is thrown.

Comment: the actual stacktrace is pretty lengthy. but i've attached the link

Comment: @kachilous: I've added the relevant part of the stacktrace (the crash) to your question.

Comment: @eldarerathis -- but what does that all mean?

Comment: @kachilous: It can't find the Activity it needs to launch at startup is what it appears to be (hence the `ClassNotFoundException`). Is the HelloWorldActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @eldarerathis - I don't believe so. All it has right now is the package name, version code 1, and version name 1.0. Where would I put HelloWorldActivity

Comment: Actually i think it does -- http://pastebin.com/gQNLHEwM

Comment: @kachilous: Try replacing `.HelloWorld.activity` with `.HelloWorldActivity` on the `<activity>` tag and see if it still crashes (not posting this as an answer yet because I'm unsure if that will solve it).

Comment: @eldarerathis - that worked! thanks. why did I have to change it to .HelloWorldActivity?

Comment: @kachilous: Good! I've added an answer with a bit of explanation as to what was going on. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, the problem was this line in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloWorld.activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

The `android:name` attribute tells the VM what class to look for when launching the activity, but your class was created as `public class HelloWorldActivity` in your .java file. Thus, when the VM tried to instantiate a `HelloWorld.activity` object, it was unable to do so, and crashed with a `ClassNotFoundException`. The solution is to change the above to read:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

...so that it matches your class definition, therefore allowing the VM to find it. Further, the reason this caused a crash immediately at start up is because the first activity entry is considered the "start up" activity.

You can find additional documentation pertaining to the manifest file [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

actually scratch my last comment.  you don't use a button as the layout to setContentView on.  create a layout, put the button on the layout, do the sentContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
then find the button (or add it to the layout)

try following the tutorial for hello world: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html